# Refreshing a html page transformed from an xml

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have written a java program, to transform a mytest.xml to mytest.html using a mytest.xslt. Lets say I have updated mytest.xml. Now, I want to add a 'Refresh' link on the mytest.html page. Clicking on this 'Refresh' link should invoke the java program to transform the updated mytest.xml to mytest.html. The 'Refresh' link should also reload the html contents in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Host your HTML on an webserver and register an servlet for. In the servlet you call the transformation chain.
Now every time you're requesting that HTML, the actual XML will get ridden and transformed.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is typically done is that instead of having the Java program write the HTML to a file, you have it write to standard output. Then when you access that Java program through the web server (if you have it set up correctly for Java), the web server will run your Java program and output whatever the Java program outputs. So, when your Java program outputs HTML, the web server will take that HTML and output it. Then, the client's web browser gets that HTML and displays it.

If you have this set up, you can very easily add a link to the original XML (which will be translated to HTML), to the Java program. So when the user clicks on the link, it will contact the web server, which will invoke your Java program again.

Comment: Thanks. But, is it possible to achieve that without using a servlet or webserver? My program is standalone one and without access to webserver.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it is. A web page doesn't (and shouldn't) have the power to run programs on the user's computer. However, you could set up a web server on your computer fairly easily. [Here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) is a guide on how to do so. Let me know if that helps.